# xpath select div with id and stop at first qualified preceding sibling which has a certain descendant

Tags: html, xpath

I'm asking for help to solve this xPATH expression.
Here is a snippet of an html source.

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="xw"/>
    <div class="icon" title="icon">
        <div class="event">
            <span class="event__title">Title</span>
            <span class="event__title_x">Title_x</span>
        </div>
        <span class="xx"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="g_1_blablabla1">blablabla1</div>
<div id="g_1_blablabla2">blablabla2</div>
<div class="x">
    <div class="xw"/>
    <div class="icon" title="icon1">
        <div class="event">
            <span class="event__title">Title1</span>
            <span class="event__title_x">Title1_x</span>
        </div>
        <span class="xx"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="g_1_blablabla3">blablabla3</div>
<div id="g_1_blablabla4">blablabla4</div>
<div class="x">
    <div class="xw"/>
    <div class="icon" title="icon2">
        <div class="event">
            <span class="event__title">Title2</span>
            <span class="event__title_x">Title2_x</span>
        </div>
        <span class="xz"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="g_1_blablabla5">blablabla5</div>
<div id="g_1_blablabla6">blablabla6</div>
```

I'd like to **get all the div elements with id starting `g_1` whose previous sibling is such a div that has descendant `span class=xx`**

So the result would be:

```
div id=g_1_blablabla1
div id=g_1_blablabla2
div id=g_1_blablabla3 
div id=g_1_blablabla4
```

because

> `g_1_blablabla1,g_1_blablabla2` have the first `div class=x` as qualified previous sibling
>
> `g_1_blablabla3, g_1_blablabla4` have the second `div class=x` as qualified previous sibling

So far I have:
`div[starts-with(@id, 'g_1')] and preceding-sibling::div[@class='x']//span[contains(@class,'xx')]]`

That is not working of course and I can't figure out the preceding-sibling part.
Anyone to help me?

Comment: thank you for the review. I've updated the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are formatting problems with the html you posted, but try this on the original html and see if it works for you:

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'g_1')][preceding-sibling::div[@class='x'][1]//span[@class='xx']]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'g_1') and preceding-sibling::div[@class='x'][1]/descendant::span[@class='xx']]
```

Comment: @Jack Fleeting was the first answering it, so I accepted his answer, but thanks - it worked as well!